# Message Does not Send from server To client in SignalR Asp.net core Web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, signalr.client

When i send message from server to client client doesn't Show the Message

This is my Program.cs file there i register Hub

```
using SignalR.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

This is My Server controller

```
  public class ServerController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Notification modal)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is JS File

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/notificationHub")
    .build();
connection.start();
console.log(connection);
connection.on("ReceiveMsg", function (msg) {
    alert('message')
    console.log('message ',msg)
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = msg;
    document.getElementById("msgList").appendChild(li);
})
```

This is my Client Side Html

```
<h1>Client App</h1>

<div id="servermsg">
    <ul id="msgList">
   

    </ul>
</div>
<script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/ClientNotification.js"></script>
```

This is my Hub File.

***When i debug the my Hub file when do not redirect when i send Message***

```
public class NotificationHub:Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMsg", message);
        }
    }
```

I update and added Program.cs File in question

Comment: Did you register the hub in `Program.cs`?

Comment: yes i register See i update the question and add program.cs file

Comment: Actually, the code works fine. As I have tested. Are you trying to send a message from the client or do you want to send a message from the index?

Comment: i create form in server controller view when i click create client page show the message

Comment: I want to send Message from Server controller Index view to Client Controller Index View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `SignalR client` (JavaScript) you will be easily able to send a message from the client too.
The `workflow` is something like this:

### JavaScript Client

1. Setup hubs and map them in the `Program.cs` (which you have done correctly)
2. Add the events to listen in the hub (In your case you did it correctly in the `NotificationHub` using the `SendMessage` method)
3. Add the SignalR client library and connect to the `hub`
4. Create the form in the view and attach an event listener (using JavaScript) when click submit
5. If have validated the previous step and you are sure it is safe to send the message call `invoke` method in the `signalR.HubConnectionBuilder`

Here is a working example of what I meant in the previous list:
**JavaScript (Client):**

```js
"use strict";

//This is your code which is working fine
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/notificationHub")
    .build();

connection.start();
console.log(connection);

connection.on("ReceiveMsg", function (msg) {
    alert('message')
    console.log('message ', msg);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = msg;
    document.getElementById("msgList").appendChild(li);
});

//New code

//Event listener attached to the submit button
document.querySelector("#form-submit-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {

    //This needs to be called if the message is validated
    //You can run this conditionally based on the logic you wanna implement
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", document.querySelector("#message-input").value);
});
```

**View**

```html
<h1>Client App</h1>

<div id="servermsg">
    <ul id="msgList">
   

    </ul>
</div>

<input type="text" id="message-input" />

<button id="form-submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

---

### .NET Client

That is said for **JavaScript client**. The procedure is the same for .NET clients

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` package from Nuget Package manager
2. Configure the dependency injection with the type of `HubConnection`
3. Start the connection in the `constructor`
4. Call the `InvokeAsync` method in your action

Here is the sample code of the `Controller`:

```cs
private readonly HubConnection _hubConnection;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("https://localhost:7159/notificationHub")
        .Build();

    _hubConnection.StartAsync();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task MessageHandler(string message)
{
    await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync<string>("SendMessage", message);
}
```

**View**

```html
<div id="servermsg">
    <ul id="msgList">
   

    </ul>
</div>

<form asp-action="MessageHandler">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message-input" />

    <button id="form-submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Microsoft Docs for `invoke` method (JS): [Call hub methods from JavaScript client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#call-hub-methods-from-the-client)

Microsoft Docs for `invoke` method (.NET C#): [Call hub methods from .NET client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#call-hub-methods-from-client)

Comment: I Want call Hub from server i also created server controller view

Comment: I have edited the question and added .NET client which is in your case ASP.NET MVC. Also, it works for any other c# project type.

Comment: No bro i just Say i have two controller One is client and Another One is server controller they both have different View there have another Index view in server Controller And different Index view in Client .in server view I add Form And submit button and  client view Used as result whenever i fill form and submit there result will be shown on client view page

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. Because the client just needs to connect to the hub through the specified URL in `HubConnectionBuilder`. Also, you said you have a server controller and client controller. Then everything is in my answer just split action methods between your controllers and make 2 actions in the server controller. One action is to return a form view and the other action is for invoking an event in the `NotificationHub`. And In your client, your code is already doing the task you want.

Comment: not working bro